# Hide/show Toolbar

Tags: android, listview, show-hide, android-toolbar

In my application, I want to hide/show the toolbar when the list is scrolling. In my opinion, I implemented everything like described in this how to show/hide under link:

https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/

The problem is, when the list is scrolled, the toolbar isn't moving/hiding.

Here is the code of the .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
        android:id="@+id/lvRef"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here are the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get nested scrolling working on ListView.
Use sticky header RecyclerView instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the toolbar on scroll down then first detect the scroll `dy` of your ListView or RecyclerView and before that get the actionBar object from toolbar.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //in on scroll listener of your view check for dy

    if (dy > 0) {
        //detecting scroll up action  
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        //detect scrolldown action dy<0
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your toolbar's layout:

use `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"` instead of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
and remove `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Answer (score 0):

To hide the toolbar you can do like that

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

To Show the toolbar again do like this way

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
```